# Oracle Deadlock issue in Container Managed Persistence (EJB2.1)

Tags: hibernate, ejb, deadlock

This is my first post & have visited occasionally for any kind of Java related issues.  This is a very useful site and the seniors members are so kind to help others.

Environment: Oracle, Jboss, EJB 2, hibernate, MDB, MQ, CMP

We are facing a deadlock issue randomly once/twice a day in our application, so I had turned on the hibernate trace.  Please is the high level code

```
@Stateless
public class SaveData() {

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
methodA(){

    Method B();
    em.persist(obj1);

    Method C();
    Method D();

    em.flush();
}

methodB(){

}

methodC(){

  em.persist(obj2);
}

methodD(){
  em.persist(obj3);
}
```

} // Bean end

Since this problem is happening only in production & no where else and I couldn't recreate it.  So I am going to add the TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW to keep it in the same transaction, now following are my questions:

1. Is the beginning of the transaction is MethodB() & ending is MethodD() or Will there be any inner new transaction?.
2. How do I check the transaction id or log message for start & end of the transaction to make sure everything is happening in one transaction?.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is the beginning of the transaction is MethodB() & ending is MethodD() or Will there be any inner new transaction?. ***No. Transaction is started from A & also ends there, as it calls other methods internally. Also you haven't specified any transaction attribute explicitly, so the default will be `Required`. Therefore, the same transaction will propagate through other methods.***
2. How do I check the transaction id or log message for start & end of the transaction to make sure everything is happening in one transaction?. ***In case of CMT not sure how to verify that, but if you want to monitor & manage it explicitly, you can have BMT. Then you will be able to start & end transaction manually.***

Comment: Thanks Nayan, So just to confirm again your 1st answer, it will be something like "begin Trans; methodA(); end Trans;" correct?.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1388356 Yes, all the internal methods(B,C & D) called from A, will be part of the same transaction.

Comment: Thanks again Nayan.  In addition to this change I am thinking of increasing ini_trans to these oracle tables so it gives little more room for the lock.  Do you think ini_trans will help in this scenario?.  Can you or some one give me some reference as how to increase the ini_trans on a table?.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1388356 You're welcome. I think ini_trans *probably* helps when multiple records of a table are altered simultaneously in independent transactions, to keep track of it. But here I assume, its sequential & accessing different tables. Also you can open a new question, it will help others to understand the case & will provide their views.

Comment: Any idea how to increase the table initrans?.  I did select ini_trans, max_trans from user_tables; returns 1 (ini_trans) & 255 (max_trans).  Now not sure how to change?.  Update user_tables set ini_trans = 2 where table_name = x; Is it correct?.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1388356 If it isn't working, you can try `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME INITRANS 5 MAXTRANS 255`.

Comment: Thanks Nayan, that worked.  I would rep you if I you tell me how to?.

Comment: Never mind I selected as answer accepted & to vote up it requires 15 reputation. So I couldn't it.

Comment: @user1388356 Glad it helped. But can't understand exactly about `I would rep you if I you tell me how to?`.

Comment: One more question, since the application is using "app_user" schema which calls "app_admin" schema (app_admin owns the table) & the database is concurrently accessed by multiple application instances at the same time.  Should I increase the ini_trans on app_user or app_admin or both?.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1388356 Probably the schema where the records gets updated eventually(app_admin not sure). I think you should open another question, so that more people can help you.

Comment: I am also implementing a rollback retry logic, to try 1 or 2 times if it happens.  So is it a good idea to put the logic where we call?.  Thanks. try{

   methodA();
} catch (LockAcquisitionException e){ 

   Thread.sleep(1000);  // Wait for a second
   methodA(); // Retry methodA again to persist

}

Comment: @user1388356 You can return the result when exception occurs, based on that retry it further. Also managing threads directly isn't recommended in EJB.